# how to skip current item in observable and go to next item in the list?

Tags: android, rx-java

I have a quiz application that shows question and each question has a count down timer and it works flawlessly but I want to know how to emit next item in the list once user clicks on a button.
below is my code is simulating getting questions from api

```
  questionObservable =  repository.getQuestionsfromlocal()
             .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
             .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())

             .concatMap(s -> {

                 if (s.getQuestion().equals("first")){
                     previousquestion_time.setValue(s.getDuration());

                     return Observable.just(s).delay(0, TimeUnit.SECONDS , AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());

                 }else{

                     return Observable.just(s).delay(previousquestion_time.getValue(), TimeUnit.SECONDS , AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());


                 }


             });


     questionObserve = new Observer<Question>() {
         @Override
         public void onSubscribe(@NonNull Disposable d) {

         }

         @Override
         public void onNext(@NonNull Question question) {
             singlequestion.setValue(question);
             previousquestion_time.setValue(question.getDuration());
         }

         @Override
         public void onError(@NonNull Throwable e) {

         }

         @Override
         public void onComplete() {

         }
     };
```

this code returns my question list as Observable.fromIteratable then I use concat map to give each question a certain delay based on previous question duration of answer.

it works automatically no problem.

what I need is when I click on a button it skips current element and go to next one and continue the flow.

Comment: Would be easier if we would see some code. I suppose there are several ways to do this

Comment: Your observable gives you a list. Just create counter variable, increment it on click and take next element in the list in position of a counter.